# How do I enable the new Google Chrome 15th birthday 2023 refresh UI?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, windows-11

My work laptop runs Google Chrome 119.0.6045.160 on Windows 10. A recent update changed the look and feel of it and a search suggests this is the [15th birthday 2023 redesign](https://blog.google/products/chrome/google-chrome-new-features-redesign-2023/).

My home laptop runs Google Chrome 119.0.6045.160 on Windows 11 and is still on the old design. I’d like to get it on to the new design.

I tried going into `chrome://flags` and enabling "Chrome Refresh 2023" and "Chrome WebUI Refresh 2023" ([source](https://www.ghacks.net/2023/08/29/how-to-enable-google-chromes-2023-refresh-new-design/)) but nothing has changed on my home laptop, even after a full reboot.

How do I enable the new Google Chrome 15th birthday 2023 refresh UI on my home laptop?

Comment: What are the Windows version on these two computers ?

Comment: I know this is not helpful, but I tried enabling those flags, and it worked for me.

Comment: Google uses a rolling update cadence for their updates, meaning they download/install/enable features slowly across all the installs. Your work laptop likely runs a managed version of Chrome that might update, or apply changes like this, at a cadence your org manages rather than one set by Google.

Comment: @harrymc Work one is Windows 10 version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.36930). My home laptop is Windows 11 version 22H2 (OS Build 22621.2715).

Comment: @caesay Are you running Windows 10 or 11? I've just enabled the flags on a different Windows 10 machine running Chrome and it works - so my current theory is that Google is not allowing the new UI on Windows 11 machines, even if you have the flags set.

Comment: For information : My Windows 11 is now on version 23H2 and has the new Chrome interface, while the "Refresh 2023" flags are all set as Default.

Comment: @harrymc That kills that theory then! Maybe my Chrome on Windows 11 is just low on the list of machines to get the new UI.

Comment: Try perhaps to upgrade to 23H2 - perhaps Chrome will behave differently.

Comment: @harrymc Odd, it's not offered in Windows Update (says I'm "up to date") despite being released a couple of months ago. Guessing I'm low down on the priority list for that too.

Comment: You could try to set [Get Windows updates as soon as they're available for your device](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-windows-updates-as-soon-as-they-re-available-for-). Just in case, I suggest creating a System Restore point before installing the 23H2 update (if it's offered), so as to be able to rollback.